# Making WP Admin Folder accessable JUST under a different link

Tags: wp-admin, htaccess

I read all your post regarding renaming and moving the admin folder a few times but I still didn't find the real answers to my question!

I got a page, lets say available under mysite.com ,the real wordpress is found under mysite.com/wordpress (of course not directly available over that link) and therefore my wp admin under mysite.com/wordpress/wp-admin/

I made the needed adaptions in the index.php and used the following commands in my .htaccess to make my wordpress available under mysite.com

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Everything is working perfect now BUT want to realise the follwing. I want to reach my admin section JUST over lets say mysite.com/secret-area and mysite.com/secretarea/ and NOT ANYMORE over mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/ or mysite.com/blog/admin

If I would be able to realise a server based password protection for that path too, it would be extremly great :)

How can I realise that over .htaccess ?

I did a lot of research and tried a lot of things but couldn't get it done in the end :/

Thx a lot for your help guys!
Nice Regards,
Stephan

Comment: Read all of whose posts? Can you link to any reference material you've found, this is a Q&A site not a blog/forum. Also can you provide more information about your install, is it a multisite? You're aware with pretty permalinks turned on that visiting /admin will redirect users to the admin panel wherever it may be?

Answer (score 0):

There's a thread about this on the Wordpress forums:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-admin-url-or-wp-admin-to-secure-login?replies=13

***The original article has three steps:***

(1) Add constant to *wp-config.php*

```
define('WP_ADMIN_DIR', 'secret-folder');
define( 'ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . WP_ADMIN_DIR);
```

(2) Add this filter to *functions.php*

```
add_filter('site_url',  'wpadmin_filter', 10, 3);
function wpadmin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ) {
    $old  = array( "/(wp-admin)/");
    $admin_dir = WP_ADMIN_DIR;
    $new  = array($admin_dir);
    return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}
```

(3) Add this line to *.htaccess* on your server

```
RewriteRule ^secret-folder/(.*) wp-admin/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

With these steps taken, your admin URL will be: http://www.yourdomain.com/secret-folder/

Comment: Can you extract the relevant information and post it as an answer? A link offsite is not an answer, and becomes useless if the URL changes or breaks

Comment: @TomJNowell - Steps added above.